# OpenID with Gerrit not working

Tags: git, openid, gerrit

When I click to Register or Sign In using Gerrit Code Review, I get this error: `Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered.`

And when I enter the URL into the OpenID field manually, it takes me to a Google page stating: `The page you requested is invalid.`

Any clue what's happening here?

**EDIT**: Upon further investigation, I realized that if I change the provided URL in the OpenID field to `http` rather than `https`, it will redirect me to Google properly and ask me to approve. However, on the redirect back to Gerrit, nothing seems to have happened. I tried registering/signing in multiple times and to no effect.

I've also looked in the `MySQL` database to see if any data was being stored, and there doesn't appear to be.

**EDIT 2**: I've now submitted [a bug report to Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=728).

**EDIT 3**: [Answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705656/openid-with-gerrit-not-working/3706615#3706615) I'd have done well to read the previous bug reports a bit more closely. My sysadmin fu is also severely lacking. Nonetheless, this is solved as a duplicate of another bug and is a Debian issue; [see below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705656/openid-with-gerrit-not-working/3706615#3706615).

Comment: Are you using Google as your OpenID account provider?

Comment: ssokolow I didn't set anything in Gerrit's `init` specifically saying so. Should I have done this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This proved to be a duplicate of [another issue](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=513).

The error was with Debian's OpenJDK Java security cacerts. Fixed by symlinking: `ln -sf /etc/java-6-sun/security/cacerts /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

I've updated my bug report to indicate that the error logs are still not generating a response that pinpoints the true cause of the error.

Comment: Excellent. You can actually choose your own answer as the official one for this question.

Comment: @VonC Thanks. I have to wait a day, sadly.

Comment: @JoshSmith whats the command for Windows equivalent to

ln -sf /etc/java-6-sun/security/cacerts /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Closest I found is mklink , but I don't know the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Is this related to [Gerrit issue 459](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=459)?

> All providers are always accepted.
>   But an administrator can configure **`auth.trustedOpenId`** to prevent users coming from an
>   unknown OpenID provider from using permissions granted to groups other than "Registered Users".
>
> The problem with **`docwhat.org`** is the XRDS document isn't a valid XML file according to our relying party library.

---

As the OP [Josh Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373496/josh-smith) mentions, a new bug has been submitted for that particular instance: **[Issue 728](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=728)**.

Comment: I'm not sure these are related issues. I actually caved and submitted the issue to Gerrit here: http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=728

Comment: @Josh: ok. I have updated my answer to include a reference to your bug report.