# Register in gerrit with OpenID failed

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to setup the gerrit these days,but when it comes to Register with OpenID,there is always a problem " Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered."
   I have seen the same question on [OpenID with Gerrit not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705656/openid-with-gerrit-not-working,and) i didn't find the answer.If this is a bug in previous version,My gerrit version is gerrit-1.2.1.6 and it shouldn't have the bug.
   I noticed that in my corporation my IP address is private 10.238.151.109,and I set the canonical URL like this http://10.238.151.109:8080,then I can access gerrit server in the local network. If it's because I use this  canonical URL and people can't access OpenID from it?
   I'm waiting for help,any help is grateful,thanks.

Comment: Now I think maybe because I ingored something when setting up gerrit,but I don't know the specific reasons.

Comment: I suggest that you try registering with a Google Account. It that works the issue might actually be connected to your OpenID provider. You always can add additional OpenID Providers to your Account later on.

Comment: I've tried to register with a Google account, but  " Provider is not supported, or was incorrectly entered." is still there.And I can access "https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount" through the browser. Why this error...?

Answer (score 0):

*I noticed that in my corporation my IP address is private*

If you use OpenID to sign in to Gerrit, you need to make sure that the OpenID provider can reach your Gerrit server.

Not long ago, I tried setting up Gerrit when I was at my university, on a WPA Enterprise network behind a firewall and god knows what other security and it would just not work, kept getting the same error as you.
 Later, at home, on a basic WPA2 network, I tried the OpenID sign-in again and it worked just fine.

In addition, you need some port forwarding to make sure the relevant requests are forwarded to the Gerrit server.

Be aware though, as of now Gerrit and Google's OpenId don't work anymore*. You can however use Yahoo's OpenID.

*See https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2677 and https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2715

Comment: Could you be more specific on the port forwarding part, please?

Comment: @Eszter you need to forward port 29418 and whatever port is used to access Gerrit Web ui to the machine that is hosting Gerrit