# OpenID registration fails with Gerrit server

Tags: ip, server, openid, virtualbox, gerrit

I have a Gerrit server running in VirtualBox and if I type in my browser its IP (which can be found out by *ifconfig -a* command) and the port, I get the web interface of Gerrit. The address in my example is:

```
192.168.1.169:8081
```

For creating projects I do need a user, so I try to register one via OpenID. However, the process gets stuck, my Firefox browser keeps saying

```
Waiting on 192.168.0.103...
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669894/register-in-gerrit-with-openid-failed) that the OpenID provider needs to know about my Gerrit server in oder to provide my OpenID for authentication.

What settings need to be done so that the OpenID provider sends the information needed *directly* to my server running in VirtualBox (attached to **Bridged Adapter**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the OpenID provider did not know about my Gerrit server. That's why the 8080 port had to be forwarded on a local router to the IP (port 8081, the one that Gerrit used) of the Gerrit server. Also, in the **gerrit.config** file the CanonicalWebUrl had to be the actual IP of the host machine, and that can be easily found out via [whatsmyipaddress](http://whatismyipaddress.com/), for instance.

Comment: ...except if it's an internal ip only and host has no public ip. I wonder is there any way to get it working then?

Comment: I guess [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669894/register-in-gerrit-with-openid-failed?lq=1) is about that as well. No solution. :(